# How to use regex negative lookahead

Tags: regex, grep, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to get the email addresses from a file using `egrep -o -e` and having trouble with addresses at the end of a line.

Here is my regex:

```
egrep -o -e "[._a-zA-Z0-9]+@[._a-zA-Z0-9]+.[._a-zA-Z0-9]+" ~/myfile.txt
```

I realize this will not catch every variation of an email address, but if the address is at the end of a line this is what I get:

```
user@_12345@myemail.com\ul
```

So I figured I'd try a negative lookahead, but I have no idea how to properly use it.  I've read a few things online but I'm confused by how it works.

This is what I've tried:

```
egrep -o -e "(?!\\[._a-zA-Z0-9]+@[._a-zA-Z0-9]+.[._a-zA-Z0-9]+)" ~/myfile.txt
```

Bash fails with `event not found: \\[._a`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does the dot stand for?

```
"[._a-zA-Z0-9]+@[._a-zA-Z0-9]+.[._a-zA-Z0-9]+"
                              ^
                             here
```

It matches the at-sign. If you remove it, your original regex with no lookahead will work.

Moreover, `!` is a special character in bash (history expansion). You have to backslash it to use it literally.

Comment: It was supposed to match the dot in an email address.  `.com` not smart?

Comment: This didn't work for me... :( `egrep -o -e "(?\!\\[._a-zA-Z0-9]+@[._a-zA-Z0-9]+.[._a-zA-Z0-9]+)" ~/myfile.txt`

Comment: @code4me: Dot is special in regexes, it matches anything. Use `\.` or `[.]` to match the dot literally.

Comment: I got this to work based on a combination of what you and @ExplosionPills suggested.  I also added `\b` to the beginning and end of the regex.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The `!` is being interpolated as a history expansion command in bash.  You should use single quotes rather than double quotes to prevent this.

However you should note that negative lookahead may not be supported by your version of `grep` either.  In this case you need a more powerful regex tool like `perl` or [`ack`](http://beyondgrep.com/).

Comment: I tried this `egrep -o -e '(?!\[._a-zA-Z0-9]+@[._a-zA-Z0-9]+.[._a-zA-Z0-9]+)' ~/myfile.txt` but no luck