# how to put captured group inside a character class to negate it?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to parse my poker hand history to determine the number of hands I played 7-2 off suit (that is, the 7 is of one suite, and the 2 is of another).

I can get the hands where I played 77 or 22

```
$ grep -E "Dealt to .* \[([7|2])[s|c|h|d]\s\1" ~/poker/handhistory/*/* | wc -l
  15
```

And the hands where I played 72 of the same suit.

```
$ grep -E "Dealt to .* \[([7|2])([s|c|h|d])\s[7|2]\2" ~/poker/handhistory/GMulligan/* | wc -l
   9
```

I've captured the rank of the first card. What I'd like to do is have a character class that contains [7] if the first capture group was 2 and [2] if the first capture group was 7.

can anyone help here?

update: 
sorry, some sample data would obviously help here

every hand that player1 is involved in has a line like this:

```
Dealt to player1 [4c Ac]
```

i'm looking specifically for all the following within the "[" and "]"

7h 2c
7h 2d
7h 2s
7c 2h
7c 2d
7c 2s
7d 2h
7d 2c
7d 2s
7s 2h
7s 2c
7s 2d

Comment: The character class `[s|c|h|d]` finds these characters: `s`, `c`, `h`, `d` and `|`.  You don't use the alternation character in a character class, but you would use it in `(s|c|h|d)`.  Better to just use `[schd]`.

Comment: ah!! thank you! I guess it shouldn't make a difference in my case. but thanks for the tip!

Comment: basically i just need somethign to negate the first capture group. as in `([7|2])[shcd]\s[7|2]BUT NOT FIRST CAPTURE GROUP[shcd]`

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use negative lookaheads to achieve what you're trying to do.

https://regex101.com/r/yK4oC7/2 (* denotes matches)

```
Dealt to player1 []
Dealt to player1 [7c 2c]
Dealt to player1 [7c 2h] *
Dealt to player1 [7d 7c]
```

Here's a breakdown of the regex `\[([72])([sdch]) (?\!\1)([72])(?\!\2)([sdch])` (In bash, `!` is a special character and must be escape. So while mamy languages execute a negative lookahead with `(?!....)`, bash appears to need `(?\!....)`.

```
\[             - match literal [
([72])         - match 7 or 2 and capter as \1
([sdch])       - match s,d,c or h
 (?!\1)([72])  - match a space followed by digit that's not the same as \1 
                 and is 7 or 2
(?!\2)([sdch]) - match sdch where it's not the same as whichever of the
                 four was matched as \1
```

Edit: I don't use bash, so I'm unfamiliar with the nuances, but the two answers to [How to use regex negative lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17791420/how-to-use-regex-negative-lookahead/17791707#17791707) should be useful in devising the proper syntax.

Comment: hmmm, i'm getting this: `-bash: !\1: event not found`

Comment: @Ramy, Try escaping the exclamation point. That appears to be your trouble from some quick googling. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17791707/3917091

Comment: @Ramy did you try escaping the !'s?

Comment: There is no lookarounds in bash regex

Comment: with escaped bang: `grep: repetition-operator operand invalid` i'm on mac osx yosemite if that matters